# Add an image/figure to the table of contents

Tags: python-sphinx, figure, restructuredtext, tableofcontents

I'm using the [alabaster](https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster) sphinx theme, and have local table of contents (TOC) on each page which automatically include my section headers.  Is there a way to also include figures/images in the TOC?

I'm including figures like:

```
.. image:: ./figs/1982MNRAS.200..115S_fig2.png
    :width: 500px
    :align: center
```

Comment: Do you want a list of figures? Why should a normal picture appear in a local ToC? No book does that.

Comment: @Paebbels because I want it in a TOC?  So that you can click and get there?  So you know which sections have figures?  So you have a list of figures that shows where they are in the text?  I didn't realize I cross-posted to *proper-book-etiquette.SE*... my bad

Comment: Currently, there is no list of figures or list of tables. It's common in LaTeX to have such lists, but not locally per page. So I think you could create a feature request at Sphinx and ask for a list of tables/figures including a local version.

Comment: You can still create your own list with labels and an enumeration. Moreover, all your images need a title.